# Font problem, just squares in some app

Tags: fonts, text

I`ve a problem with some apps. Every letter apears just like square.
First I discovered it when I want to save or print somethink in Opera the window that apears after ctrl + s contains just squares.
[squares in Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EVLt.png)

[squares in galculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB9xz.jpg)